# Inserting and fetching the Large JSON document in Couchbase?

Tags: json, couchbase, couchbase-java-api

I am trying to insert the Large JSON document in the Couchbase. I have inserted the document like below.

```
Bucket bucket = cluster.openBucket("default");
String jsondoc = "{{
"exams": {
    "exam1": {
        "year": {
            "math": {
                "questions": [
                    {
                        "question_text": "first question",
                        "options": [
                            "option1",
                            "option2",
                            "option3",
                            "option4",
                            "option5"
                        ],
                        "answer": 1,
                        "explaination": "explain the answer"
                    },
                    {
                         "question_text": "second question",
                        "options": [
                            "option1",
                            "option2",
                            "option3",
                            "option4",
                            "option5"
                        ],
                        "answer": 1,
                        "explaination": "explain the answer"
                    },
                    {
                        "question_text": "third question",
                        "options": [
                            "option1",
                            "option2",
                            "option3",
                            "option4",
                            "option5"
                        ],
                        "answer": 1,
                        "explaination": "explain the answer"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "english": {same structure as above}
        },
        "1961": {}
    },
    "exam2": {},
    "exam3": {},
    "exam4": {}
}
}}";

JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
jsonObj.put("examinfo", jsondoc);
bucket.upsert(JSONDocument.create("exam", jsonObj));
```

After Inserting the document like above, I want to retrieve individual nested nodes(ex: questions) while fetching.

I have the following queries:
1) Can I Insert the document by using traditional approach:
  String query = "upsert into default(KEY, VALUE) values(jsondoc)";
statement.executeUpdateQuery(query);
 or Should I need to insert the above nested nodes individually in each JSONObject to fetch the nested nodes properly?

2) How to use N1QLQueryResult to fetch the each json document as a row only to fetch required json information

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Couchbase are you using?  There is a sub-doc API in version 4.5 that is for operating on parts of a JSON document:

http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.5-dp/sub-doc-api.html

For your second question, you may want to look into the UNNEST N1QL operator.

Comment: I am using Couchbase 4.0

Comment: Hello @beamatronic, I am inserting the entire document in only one put of jsonObject. So Is it possible to get the part of json document?

Comment: As @beamatronic said: yes, you can use UPSERT or INSERT. You need to specify expressions for both KEY and VALUE. See the syntax in docs. For retrieval, UNNEST will give you each question as a separate row. Or you can specify an array subscript to retrieve a question by its position.

Comment: Hello @geraldss, Thank you for the response. I tried to array subscript. but I was not able to get it. It would be great If you could point me some examples. Mean while I will fetch it by using UNNEST .

Comment: LMK if UNNEST works for you. Array subscript means exams.exam1.year.math.questions[0].

Comment: Both of them are not working for me. I think Its because of insertion of whole document is in the form of string at a stretch or really i am using single quote(') instead od double quotes for key value pair in Json docment string. Please Let me know If you have any idea

Comment: I am not able to fetch the nested node, because of my insertion is not proper. Am I right?